# For SafeHtml, Do we need to sanitize the "link" in <img src=link> tag, GWT?

Tags: image, gwt, tags, sanitize

I got a textbox that allows users to put image link (ex: http://abc.test.gif) & another textbox that allows user to put Alternate text (ex: "This is test.gif"), & a submit button.

When a user clicks on submit buton, the program will generate `<img src="http://abc.test.gif" alt="This is test.gif">` this string & store it into DB for later use.

My question is: do i need to sanitize the imagelink `"http://abc.test.gif"` & the text in alt tag `"This is test.gif"`

For example, do i need to use `UriUtils.isSafeUri("http://abc.test.gif");` & `SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("This is test.gif"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are deliberately allowing the user to input anything he want that will go into the `src` and the `alt` attributes of the `img` tag. This is indeed open to any kind of XSS attack. Have a look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Malformed_IMG_tags) for some examples that still work in recent browsers.

Also, you are storing the string in your DB for later use (guessing), so the *attack* may occur at later time, when you will use such string to create a node in the DOM, with even more unpredictable results.

One solution could be to store only the URL and the alternative string in the database (with a proper input validation, if any), and generate the *safe* `img` snippet right when you need it, with a simple template like the following (or programmatically using `SafeHtmlBuilder`).

```
public interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\"/>")
  SafeHtml img(SafeUri uri, SafeHtml alternativeText);
}
```

To be used like:

```
template.img(
    UriUtils.fromString(yourValidatedDbUrl),
    SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(yourValidatedAlternativeText));
```

This way you:

- validate the user input;
- store only the validated values (as-are);
- generate the img snippet in a safe way only when really needed.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, very few people can answer this.