# GWT html object show text as url or img

Tags: html, gwt

I get a URL as text from database and put it into an HTML object and add this object to layout.
I want this text to work as URL or IMG.
you can see in the code what I have tried. didn't find a method that does that...

my code :

```
                        int listSize = result.size();
                        int i;


                        assetPanel.clear();
                                for(i=0;i<listSize;i++)
                                {
                                    HorizontalPanel vPanelPic = new HorizontalPanel();
                                    HTML picSpace = new HTML();
                                    picSpace.setHTML("<img src = " + result.get(i).getUrl() + "style=width:304px;height:228px>");
                                    //Window.alert("<a href " + result.get(i).getUrl()+ "</a>");
                                    vPanelPic.add(picSpace);
                                    assetPanel.add(vPanelPic);

                                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Try this:

```
// img: 
picSpace.setHTML("<img src='" + result.get(i).getUrl() + "' style='width:304px;height:228px'>");

// link:
Window.alert("<a href='" + result.get(i).getUrl() + "'>URL</a>");
```

Comment: Congratulations, now you're vulnerable to all sorts of XSS / XSI! Pro Tip: use `SafeHtml` (and `SafeHtmlTemplates` to make it easier) and `SafeUri`.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer
HTML picSpace = new HTML();
     
  SafeHtmlBuilder safePicHtml = new SafeHtmlBuilder();

       safePicHtml.appendHtmlConstant("<imgsrc='").appendEscaped(result.get(i).getUrl()).appendHtmlConstant("'style='width:304px;height:228px'>");
Is this the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that post solves the problem without any security issues :

[For SafeHtml, Do we need to sanitize the "link" in <img src=link> tag, GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392625/for-safehtml-do-we-need-to-sanitize-the-link-in-img-src-link-tag-gwt)